# linux-image-generic seems to be broken

Tags: 12.04, apt, dpkg

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. Recently I can't install anything anymore. I always get the following error message:

```
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic (3.2.0-34.53) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Use of chdir('') or chdir(undef) as chdir() is deprecated at /var/lib/dpkg/inf/linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic.postinst line 235.
Failed to symbolic-link /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic to initrd.img:File exists at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic.postinst line 614.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 17
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.34.37); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up dselect (1.16.1.2ubuntu7) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                         No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The output of `dpkg -C` is:

```
The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure menu option in dselect for them to work:
 linux-image-generic  Generic Linux kernel image
 linux-generic        Complete Generic Linux kernel

The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems configuring them the first time. The configuration should be retried using dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x8
```

but `dpkg --configure linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic linux-image-generic linux-generic` results in the following error message:

```
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic (3.2.0-34.53) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Use of chdir('') or chdir(undef) as chdir() is deprecated at /var/lib/dpkg/inf/linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic.postinst line 235.
Failed to symbolic-link /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic to initrd.img:File exists at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic.postinst line 614.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 17
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.34.37); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
```

I would be very glad if someone could help me with this problem!

Comment: Try `rm /initrd.img` an run that `dpkg --configure` again.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't help, still the same error message. Thank you for the quick answer though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bogus `pwd` (print working directory) command, somehow. I took a look at the referenced line in the postinst script. It is trying to "save" the working directory by storing the output of `pwd` in a variable, and then, on the referenced line, switching back to this directory after doing a few things in other directories. The problem happens because the `pwd` called somehow has empty output.

Run the command `which pwd`. If the output isn't `/bin/pwd`, find out why and fix it.

Comment: `pwd` seems to work fine and `which pwd` outputs `/bin/pwd` as it should.

Comment: I played around with some perl scripts and I noticed that `pwd` doesn't work from within perl apparently, it just returns an empty string. Running `which pwd` from within the perl script returns `/bin/pwd` though. How is this possible? As I said above, running `pwd` in the terminal works just fine...

Comment: That's really weird. I'm trying to figure out why that would be, but I'm no perl expert. In any case, I'm fairly certain that it's a bug that the postinst script calls `pwd` instead of using Perl's own `Cwd` like it ought to.

Comment: I substituted all occurrences of `pwd` in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic.postinst` with `getcwd()` and now everything seems to work again!
Thanks a lot, tgies!

Comment: I was going to suggest that as a solution to your immediate problem. It is still a point of concern that pwd isn't working from Perl for you.

Comment: That seems odd to me, `pwd` seems to work in nieve test:    $ perl
    $foo=`pwd`;
    print($foo);
    /home/apw
    $