# dpkg Unmet dependency linux-image-generic 13.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, 13.10, dpkg, dependencies

I've upgraded a few of my boxes to 13.10 and have started to see the following error on them when running `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`:

```
Setting up linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic (3.11.0-13.20) ...
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-13-generic)
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic depends on linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

From a few other [threads on similar errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233798/linux-image-generic-seems-to-be-broken), it seems it may be an issue with `pwd` output in pearl from an install script. Since it's happening on all the 13.10 boxes, I'm assuming this is a larger issue than just for me.

Output of `dpkg -L linux-image`:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/linux-image
/usr/share/doc/linux-image/copyright
/usr/share/doc/linux-image/changelog.gz
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant `dpkg -l linux-image*`.